Why does PostgreSQL database size increase even though WAL limits or checkpoint are not hit
We use HammerDB/PostgreSQL for Hardware performance characterization. The PostgreSQL database is tuned to showcase the best hardware performance (checkpoint set to 1hr, min_wal_size as 256GB, max_wal_size as 500GB, etc.). The HammerDB workload is set up with 1000 warehouses. We run HammerDB only for 10-15 minutes.
Our database is mounted on a separate disk (at /mnt/data). While running the HammerDB workload for the particular VM setting (at high enough virtual Users), I see the data disk size increase around 0.5 to 1GB/min. The majority of that growth comes from the directory (/mnt/data/13/main/base), followed by pg_subtrans and pg_stat_tmp. Given we are running a workload for a short enough duration and within the WAL limit, I assumed all the transactions will be written to the WAL only, which means only the WAL directory (/mnt/data/13/main/pg_wal) would show growth. But instead it looks like the database is actually growing. Please help me fill in the gaps in my understanding. Thank You

Why wouldn't the database(~/base/)grow in size? WAL are just the log files, the data itself is going into the table files which are under ~/base/. At some point, assuming correct setup, unneeded WAL files will be recycled. The data itself will persist minus dead tuples reclaimed by (AUTO)VACUUM.

When a table is extended by a page, that new zero page is always written to the datafile immediately. This way an out-of-space condition is detected immediately, not just later when the data needs to get checkpointed.
